# $|\{x \in O \mid \operatorname{dist}(x, \mathbb{R} \setminus O) < \varepsilon\}| \geq C \varepsilon$ for all $0<\varepsilon < \delta$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

Let $O \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty open set.

Does there exist $C, \delta >0$ such that $|\{x \in O \mid \operatorname{dist}(x, \mathbb{R} \setminus O) < \varepsilon\}| \geq C \varepsilon$ for all $0<\varepsilon < \delta$ ?

Comment: What have you tried, what are your thoughts? Do you know that an open subset of R is a (countable) union of open, disjoint intervals?

Comment: \backslash and \setminus do not yield identical results. Look: $$ \begin{align} & A\backslash B \\ \\ & A \setminus B \end{align} $$ They look different, and the reason it's done that way is the same reason that there's more space between $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$ and $\text{“}5\text{''}$ in $\text{“}3+5\text{''}$ than in $\text{“}{+5}\text{''}.$ I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0\in O$. Now, since $O\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$ we have $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus O$. Suppose wlog $y>x_0$ and take $I:=\left[x_0,x_1\right[$ where $x_1=\sup\left\{x\in O\mid\left[x_0,x\right[\subseteq O\right\}$. Now, let $\delta:=d(x_0,x_1)$ and $d_\varepsilon(O):=\{x\in O\mid d(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus O)<\varepsilon\}$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. This is the moment to note that $(x_1-\varepsilon,x_1)\subseteq d_\varepsilon(O)$ provided that $\delta>\varepsilon>0$. Hence, $\varepsilon=\lambda(\left]x_1-\varepsilon,x_1\right[)\leq\lambda(d_\varepsilon(O))$

Comment: What about the following? Let $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty open set.

Does there exist $C, \delta >0$ such that $|\{x \in O \mid \operatorname{dist}(x, \mathbb{R} \setminus O) < \varepsilon\}| \geq C {\varepsilon}^n$ for all $0<\varepsilon < \delta$ ?

Comment: Interesting. I guess this is true. The following is just an idea and a possibly a sketch of proof.
Take the section of $O$ by hyperplanes of the form $\pi_a:x_n=a$. Then by induction each $O_a=\pi_a\cap O$ satisfy the theorem for $\varepsilon^{n-1}$ and to get the hypotesis you can integrate $\chi_{d_\varepsilon(O)}$ (the characteristic function of $d_\varepsilon(O)$) to get the volume, first along $x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ and then along $x_n$, using induction hypotesis.
Here $O$ is open, the hyperplanes are closed, so each set in play is Borel, hence its characteristic function is measurable.

Comment: Another - nice - way could be to find Romeo&Juliet spheres. I.E. tho balls $R:=B_{\varepsilon_1}(x)$ and $J:=B_{\varepsilon_2}(y)$ such that $R\subseteq O$ and $J\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\setminus O$ such that Romeo kisses Juliet or, more formally, $\partial{R}\cap\partial{J}\neq\emptyset$.
I guess this case implies the assertion for the whole $O$-case and its way simpler (an integral calculation, roughly speaking)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that, by $\left| A\right|$ you mean the measure $\lambda(A)$ of the set (if you intend the cardinality of $A$ the question make no sense to me). Well, I think the question is about boundedness. Let $O=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left]n-\frac{1}{4},n+\frac{1}{4}\right[$. Now, for every choice of $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that your set, namely $d_\varepsilon(O):=\left\{x\in O\mid d(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus O)<\varepsilon\right\}$ (a sort of approximation of $\partial{O}$), has measure $\lambda(d_\varepsilon(O))=+\infty$. In fact it happens to be a (countable) union of open intervals all of the same - positive - size.

Comment: In that case, the claim is established.

Comment: I read $\leq$ instead of $\geq$... :D

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I take just any open interval $I \subset O$ (which can be done since $O$ is open), and if I set $C=2$ and $\delta = \frac{|I|}{2}$, then your statement will hold (?)